# Generate a 3D object from an image texture

Tags: modeling, texturing

Would there be any way to generate a 3D mesh **(that would conserves the shape of the original textured object as if shrinkwraped)** from a black and transparent 2D texture?

For example, on the image below, the objective would be to generate a mesh from the black color only, (separating it from the transparent part of the texture)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "shrinkwrapped" plane and "3D object"? The texture only has 2 dimensions, meaning that as a _plane_ it'll be a XY two-dimensional object. Did you mean create a mesh with surface only there's black in your example (ignoring what was said about planes because it has nothing to do with the question)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is confusing and the OP didn't clarify it yet, but I don't want to risk losing the drafted answer to what I *think* is the issue, so here it is.

Geometry Nodes make it simple to generate a mesh from a texture applied on something.

The idea is to capture the texture in the base mesh points, deleting those falling outside the value threshold. This will leave you with a mesh containing only the vertices painted in the desired value.

[image: Texture-based mesh cutout]

Most work here is done to ensure the mesh is dense enough to capture the texture faithfully. Use the basic **Subdivide Mesh** node whenever possible, because the Subsurf one is much more performance-intensive.

This texture was created directly in Geometry Nodes. You can load external ones using the **Image Texture** node instead, plugging your UVmap in the vector input.

It's a good idea to **Decimate** the resulting mesh, because it's likely to be dense enough to slow blender to a crawl.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable "Add Images as Planes" Add-on.
2. Add an image of choice:

[image]

3. In numbers panel remove the rotations of the object.
4. Create a Geometry Nodes setup:

[image]

5. You can now disable the material's transparency by changing [image] *Material Properties > Settings > Blend Mode* to *Opaque*, and yet the object will remain transparent:

[image]

6. The reason why it's so slow is that the topology has to be dense in order to hit the edges with the vertices. You can now apply the modifier (perhaps you want to apply it without the *Extrude Mesh* node), and then use *Decimate* to limit the amount of geometry.

Comment: Do the 2 *Subdivide Mesh* nodes prevent the flat-shaded artifacts or what are they good for? (You could enter the number 10 to exceed the slider limit of 6). -- Wow the *Extrude Mesh* node creates a lot of inner faces. You noted that in point 6, right? Wouldn't a *Solidify* node be a better choice?

Comment: @Blunder that must be because I left Individual selected, I didn't actually investigate the mesh, as it was laggy enough to demotivate from playing with it... I know how soft limits work and I'm pretty sure I checked if I can input manually more than 6, so either it was fixed recently or... Or maybe it's one of the cases where I'm pretty sure but still wrong :D

Answer (score 1):

By now there are already two answers, but I'm posting my started answer anyway because it shows how to use the UV map and it features the *Compare* node with colors. Maybe it will help someone.

The *Subdivision Surface* modifier is used because the *Catmill-Clark* mode gives you a smoother result than the *Subdivide Mesh* node in *Geometry* nodes that basically has only the *Simply* mode. (You can see the "flat-shaded" artifacts of *Simple* mode on a sphere.)

The "3D sculpts" have also a *Solidify*, *Smooth* and *Decimate* modifier to reduce the poly-count. Warning: Don't try to move around such a mesh with all the modifiers active because it creates a crazy lag and makes Blender unresponding. Turn them off with the "monitor icon" before you move the object.

The sphere at the top left is the textured original model. The other ones are created with the modifiers.

[image: example]

Comment: There's *Subdivision Surface* node: https://i.imgur.com/xSaLWTS.png

Comment: Oh, thanks! I see, this is what Rhaenys mentioned. So, *Subdivide Mesh* is kinda like the *Subdivision Surface* modifier in *Simple* mode and the *Subdivision Surface* node is like the *Subdivision Surface* modifier in *Catmill-Clark* mode:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPyyH.jpg