# How to delete the vertices and faces from the transparent parts of an alpha channel?

Tags: transparency

I have a Body mesh with a UV combined with an image texture which has transparent parts through its alpha channel.

I need to delete or dissolve the vertices and faces of those transparent parts and turn the mesh into a new, clean object.

Made a vertices group of the visible vertices and then used a modifier to dissolve the other vertices. But that won't work all the time because with low res objects visible and transparent vertices overlap, so the result won't match exactly.

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshot?

Comment: Please provide screen shots of your current issue so we can better understand your question. You can paste them directly into the post.

Comment: I don't understand the last part and what's the problem. With Geometry Nodes, you can delete vertices based on the transparency mask (https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/264833/107598). Might be helpful

Comment: @Moonboots and JakeMoyo. screenshots has nothing to do with it I just need some vertices deleted when there transparent.

Comment: @Blunder Thanks